# Getting pygame key constant ea K_UP from an event

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to pass the event to another function and I need the key constant as a string. Is there a way to get it?
`pygame.key.name(ev.key)` just gives me `Up` instead of `K_UP`
I did try `pygame.key.key_code(pygame.key.name(ev.key))` but looks like sdl2 doesn't have that function.

---

Here's a very valid use case for it:
I already have this function that gets the pressed button's key and does something with it, and it accepts a string. Since It's already working, I wanted to keep it simple and use the same function.

```py
def input(self, key):
    for i in self.moves:
        if key in i.keys:
            i.change("_correct")
        else:
            i.change("_wrong")
        self.next()
        return
```

And I didn't come on saying: There should be a function to do this or that, I just asked if there's a way like getting the value from some dictionary that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself why you want to do this? For what purpose? What is wrong with `ev.key`? Of course SDL does not have this function, because it has no use. `ev.key` contains a number and the key constants (`K_`*) are also numbers. So you can compare them. But the event object has no reference to the corresponding key constant.

What you are actually trying to do is

```py
a = 5
b = a
```

and then you want to get the name "a" from `b`. This is not possible.

---

Anyway, you can try to calculate the name manually:

```py
name = pygame.key.name(event.key)
kName = 'K_' + (name if len(name)==1 else name.upper())
```

example:

```py
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            name = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            kName = 'K_' + (name if len(name)==1 else name.upper()) 
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key), kName)
```

output:

```
up K_UP
w K_w
right K_RIGHT
d K_d
down K_DOWN
s K_s
left K_LEFT
a K_a
```